# If $A$ has orthonormal columns then $||Ax||^2_2 = ||x||^2_2$, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

In the lecture notes we have a fact:

> If $A$ has orthonormal columns then $||Ax||^2_2 = ||x||^2_2$

Why is it the case? What properties of matrix-vector multiplication should I know to reason about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $A$ has orthonormal columns is expressed concisely by the statement that $A^T A = I$. It follows from this fact that
\begin{align}
\| Ax \|^2 &= (Ax)^T Ax \\
&= x^T A^T A x \\
&= x^T x \\
&= \| x \|^2.
\end{align}

---

Here's an alternative proof. Let $u_i$ be the $i$th column of $A$ and let $x_i$ be the $i$th component of a vector $x$. If $y = Ax = \sum_i x_i u_i$, then
\begin{align}
 \|y\|^2&= \sum_i \| x_i u_i \|^2 \qquad \text{(by Pythagorean theorem)} \\
&= \sum_i x_i^2 \| u_i \|^2 \\
&= \sum_i x_i^2 \\
&= \| x \|^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ has orthonormal columns, $A^TA=I$.